# Need help integrating the math class in a windows forms calculator

Tags: c#, winforms

First of all I'm sorry for the bad title. I'm a beginner so I don't have the vocabulary to accurately express what I need help with within one sentence.

I am currently trying to program a calculator. The calculator looks like this:[image]

All of the buttons in the left area are working perfectly, but I'm having trouble coding for the buttons on the right. The program works by simply taking the string in the display and calculating it, but that doesn't work with the buttons on the right. For example I want the display to show √x and calculate the answer by using `Math.Sqrt(x)` when the user presses the √-button, I don't want the display to show Math.Sqrt(x).

My code looks like this:

```
public partial class Calculator : Form
    {
        String mathOperator;

        public Calculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void number_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbxDisplay.Text == "0")
            {
                tbxDisplay.Clear();
            }

            Button btnNumber = (Button)sender;
            tbxDisplay.Text = tbxDisplay.Text + btnNumber.Text;
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbxDisplay.Text = "0";
        }

        private void operator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btnOperator = (Button)sender;
            mathOperator = btnOperator.Text;

            if ((btnOperator.Text == "(" ) && tbxDisplay.Text == "0")
            {
                tbxDisplay.Clear();
                tbxDisplay.Text = tbxDisplay.Text + btnOperator.Text;
            }


            else
            {
                tbxDisplay.Text = tbxDisplay.Text + btnOperator.Text;
            }

        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            var v = dt.Compute(tbxDisplay.Text, "");

            string answer = v.ToString();
            answer = answer.Replace(',', '.');

            if (answer.Contains(".0"))
            {
               answer = answer.TrimEnd('0');

               if (answer.EndsWith(".")) 
                    answer = answer.TrimEnd('.');
            }

            tbxDisplay.Text = answer;
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbxDisplay.Text.Length > 0 && tbxSDisplay.Text.Length != 1)
            {
                tbxDisplay.Text = 
                tbxDisplay.Text.Remove(tbxDisplay.Text.Length - 1, 1);
            }

            if (tbxDisplay.Text.Length == 1)
            {
                tbxDisplay.Text = "0";
            }
        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }


        private void btnPi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbxDisplay.Text = tbxDisplay.Text + "3.14159265359";
            //this is my solution for now
            //but as you can see it's very ugly
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you thought about using the Tags that can be placed on the buttons and using those to base your calculation? That way, you can set the tag of the square root operation to something like: `sqrt` and not have to worry about character errors/inaccuracies.

Comment: You either have an event handler for each button,or use what @RyanC Suggested